# Algorithm for iterating through a loop with different upper bounds

Tags: java

The idea is to basically iterate through a set of bounds such as:

```
bounds = {50000, 100000, 150000, 200000};
```

and then to basically have a loop that will perform an iteration on something for 50000 times. When that is done, move to 100000, and so forth. I haven't worked with java in a while, so I know I can use a for loop for the actual nested loop that performs the operations that I want to do multiple times, but I'm not sure what the best implementation would be to iterate through the bounds so that I can turn 4 for loops into a 2-level nested loop.

I think maybe doing this may work, but not sure if it's the best implementation.

```
int[] bounds = {50000, 100000, 150000, 200000};

for (int n : primes) {
     //do stuff to n
}
```

Comment: Your task is not clear.  Try a more detailed description.

Comment: so you want to check primes numbers for each bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int[] bounds = new int[]{50000, 100000, 150000, 200000};
for(int bound : bounds){
    for(int i=0 ; i<bound ; i++){
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
  int[] arr = {10,20,30,40};

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < arr[i]; j++ )
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay that what was my original idea, but looking at my edits I just made will that also work?

Comment: Looking at your edit, I presume you meant `bounds` where you wrote `primes`. If so, this won't give you the same behaviour as the nested loop. The single loop is just iterating through the elements in your array.